# Handling JSF ViewState errors using JMeter

Tags: performance, load-testing, jmeter

I'm facing an issue while running a recorded test scenario of an application login using a single user on JMeter.

I've used JMeter's proxy server to record all the requests of the login scenario.
The proxy server records all the requests fine. When i play the recorded scenario, the login step gives response data that contains "Your session has expired". It seems that the JSF ViewState value is getting hard-coded when I record the requests due to which when the steps are played the new ViewState values generated from the server do not match.

I tried using solutions given in these links to handle ViewState values:

- [Testing a JSF Application with JMeter](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter)
- [How to handle JSF viewstate with jmeter](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=572893)
- [JMeter handling dynamic ViewState parameter in Seam framework](http://anahorny.blogspot.in/2011/03/jmeter-handling-dynamic-viewstate.html)
- [How to modify JMeter scripts which handle JSF ViewState?](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-to-modify-JMeter-scripts-which-handle-JSF-ViewState-td525955.html).

But still it doesn't work.
Am i missing something?
Or is it something other than the ViewState that's causing the recorded steps to fail?

Screenshots below:

screen #1
[image: screen #1]

screen #2
[image: screen #2]

screen #3
[image: screen #3]

Comment: I used the procedure in [your first link](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter) and it worked.

Comment: it's not working. These are the steps i followed:
1. Recorded the steps using the proxy server.
2. Added a user-defined variable 'jsfViewState' to the Thread Group.
3. Added a RegEx Extractor to the Thread Group with reference name 'jsfViewState' and value as    <input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(.+?)" />
4. Modified the javax.faces.ViewState Request Parameter for the login steps as ${jsfViewState} and any further requests that are using the ViewState parameter.
5. Played the steps.

Comment: Are these the steps you followed too?

Comment: You have to keep changing the "ViewState" in every POST. You extract the ViewState and insert it in the next POST. This is allways changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You have to extract viewState value BEFORE the usage.
I.e. if you send viewState value along with login-request so you have to extract this value from response to PREVIOUS request.

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Request 01 : /login GET
        XPath Extractor : extract jsfViewState
    HTTP Request 02 : /login POST (send previously extracted jsfViewState as param)
        XPath Extractor : extract jsfViewState for next request
    . . .
```

2) You are extracting viewState to the variable `${Var_ViewState}` (screen #1) but refer it as `${ViewState}` (screen #3).
Be careful.

3) In your XPath Extractor (screen #1) you have to check [Use Tidy (tolerant parser)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) checkbox on the element's control panel - since you are using xpath against html, not xml (presume that some kind of warning should also appear in jmeter.login this case).
XPath query itself looks good, although string() is redundant.

4) Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test-plan to handle session variables (jsessionid).

Comment: Sorry about refering to the Var_ViewState variable as ${ViewState}. I did realize that after posting my query here. But correcting the reference still didn't help me.
I haven't tried the steps 1,3,4 you mentioned. Will check that and revert back. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I enabled the Use Tidy (tolerant parser) checkbox. And also used the HTTP Cookie Manager. But I have just added a HTTP Cookie Manager to the Thread Group. Do i have to make any changes / add any cookies in the Cookie Manager?
It's still not working.

Comment: @ Abhijeet, HOW it's not working? Is jsfViewState extracted? What's in jmeter.log? Simply add HTTP Cookie Manager at the top level (Test Plan), that's should be enough. Have you encoded jsfViewState value upon sending along with request ("Encoded" checkbox, http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter -> Some Notes)?

Comment: jmeter.log:
http://pastebin.com/yAij3w5H

Yes, i've added HTTP Cookie Manager at the top level (Test Plan). And i've set the encoded checkbox for jsfViewState to checked.
I have referenced jsfViewState as ${jsfViewState} in the parameters (after the login request) of any requests that contain ViewState in their headers.
I'm very much confused as to what's exactly not working.
I'm completely a JMeter newbie, so please bear with me.

Comment: Okay. Once more. See point #1 in answer above - I've added schema to use. To send jsfViewState value along with login POST request you need somehow extract it (ViewState) before - e.g. send login GET first. You will extracted jsfViewState value on each request to use it in the NEXT one - but not in the same.

Comment: So do you mean I should add a new XPath Extractor + a user defined variable for every request in the request tree in JMeter?

Comment: Yes. But what you have to do in the first hand - add something like /login GET request, without params, before your /login POST - and extract 1st ViewState value and send it along with further /login POST.

Comment: [How do I ask?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Yes, i was still working on the issue so wasn't reverting back. I later found that it's possible to use Selenium JUnit test cases with JMeter. I tried that and it's working. So, as of now, i've kept JSessionID and ViewState aside.
Thankyou for the great help! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Just one change worked for me Jmeter 2.13.
>
> In Screen 1 change ${Var_ViewState} to ${jsfViewState}
>   since you are
>   using ${ViewState} in Screen 2 change that to ${jsfViewState}

Note

> 1. Checking Tidy (tolerant parser) doesn't work.
> 2. my xpath query was string(//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value)
> 3. I used the jmeter proxy recording to generate the test plan. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
> 4. No changes were made on the encoding on the recorded script
> 5. Change the javax.faces.ViewState parameter to ${jsfViewState} in all the recored files.